# С++, задана матрица (8х12)

Tags: c++, массивы

Задана матрица (8х12). Надо найти такие элементы, слева от которых в строке все элементы меньше, а справа больше. Думаю уже 3 дня, никак не могу решить.

Comment: Вы хотите отсортировать каждую строку по возрастанию, я правильно понял?

Comment: Сортировать не нужно, нужно в матрице, заполненной случайными числами найти такие элементы.

Comment: Так, и в чем сложность? Вы какой-то код уже начали писать? Что в нем не работает?

Comment: Вы правда три дня думали? Или три дня назад вы прочитали задачу, отложили её в сторону, а теперь вспомнили, что её нужно всё-таки сделать? Потому что если вы и правда три дня думали и не нашли решение - бросайте программирование, это совсем не ваше, а дальше будет только значительно сложнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идём по строке слева направо, записывая в дополнительный массив `N[]` текущий максимум на пройденном участке, не включая текущий индекс  (`N[i] = max(A[0]..A[i-1])`)

Идём по строке справа налево, поддерживая в переменной `Mn` текущий минимум на правой части.
Если для i-го элемента `A[i] < Mn` и `A[i] > N[i]`, то он подходит

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я, что-то, протупил, так сказать.